# vertical-align doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a following example: https://jsfiddle.net/er322dLL/

```css
.form-check-input:checked+span {
  text-decoration: line-through
}

.form-check-input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container alert-info alert">

  <label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 2em;">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" style="zoom: 1.5">
         <span>Text</span>
      </label>

</div>
```

Even if I used vertical-align, my checkbox is still not aligned properly. I found out, that when I add position:relative it works, but still I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me why it's necessary to add this propery. I'm quite new to CSS/HTML and probably don't understand it at all.

Comment: `zoom: 1.5` is not valid CSS. There is no `zoom` property in CSS.

Comment: @connexo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: The MDN page clearly states that it is non-standard and shouldn't be used. So instead of using `zoom: 1.5`, one should be using `transform: scale(1.5)`

Comment: the misalignment in @Witnes's fiddle is because of Horizontal alignment, not vertical alignment lol You don't have to add more css to your bootstrap site as the other answers suggest, There is already a class for that. Check my answer lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`vertical-align` is a slightly misnamed property and it's only vertically aligning inline elements, not blocks like you're probably expecting.

See this codepen I put together:
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/OXzNRj

Broadly, there are two kinds of HTML elements: block-level elements and inline elements. You define them with `display: block;` and `display: inline`. Where beginners get confused is that they don't realize **every element already has a display orientation defined by the browser**.

The elements you are using, like `<div>`, `<section>`, etc are predefined as blocks, but some like `<label>` are inline. So you'd have to first make all of your element inline elements, but you'd find that doesn't work very well either.

The main way to do layouts in 2018 is with [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which controls alignment on two axes very tightly. The main axis is controlled by the `justify-content` property and the secondary axis is controlled by the `align-items` property. By default, flexbox is oriented into rows so vertical control is handled with `align-items: center;` most of the time.

You set the `display: flex;` and the `align-items: center` properties on the container which contains the objects you're trying to vertically center. In your case thats `<label class="form-check-input">`, so the code would be:

```
.form-check-input {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an **inline or table-cell** box.

[MDN info about vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Input is rendered with display: block in this case.

To vertically align block elements you can use one of the multiple solutions available, depending on your case:

a) browser support(flexbox)

b) absolute positioning with negative margins,

etc.

Comment: A checkbox, as other `input` elements, is _[Flow Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)_ which is _inline_ or _inline-block_

Comment: Question still is, why when I used position: relative it worked?

Comment: @Witnes That's because one of your external resources (probably bootstrap) is setting the **position** of the checkbox to **absolute**. By default, it should be **static**. So even doing `position: static` would work.

Answer (score 1):

See @August's answer for why it didn't work.

Here's a workaround using **flexbox**

```
.form-check-input:checked+span {
    text-decoration: line-through
}

.form-check-label{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

For further details, refer to [Basic Concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

The misalignment in @Witnes's fiddle is because of Horizontal alignment, not vertical alignment lol You don't have to add more css to your bootstrap site when there is already a class `form-check-inline` for that.

---

Just wrap the label element with a `.form-check-inline` div like this:

```
<div class="form-check-inline">
  <label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 2em;">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" style="zoom: 1.5" [checked] = "item.done" (click)="toggleDone()">
     <span>Text</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

and remove the vertical-inline css that you have added.

You are trying to change the vertical alignment when the horizontal alignment is what you are actually looking for.

`form-check` is a bootstrap class for vertically centering form elements.

`form-check-inline` is a bootstrap class for horizontally centering form elements.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er322dLL/2/

Answer (score 0):

As @August said, that property works in a table-cell, so try something along the lines of this:

```css
.container {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
}
.centered-form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-check-input:checked+span {
  text-decoration: line-through
}

.form-check-input {
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    /* NOTE: I'd use a container so you can more easily keep the label and item together */
}
```

```html
<div class="container alert-info alert">
  <div class="centered-form">
  <label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 2em;">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" style="zoom: 1.5">
         <span>Text</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be add `vertical-align` all the child elements of your `label` element:

```css
.form-check-input:checked+span {
  text-decoration: line-through
}

.form-check-label * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container alert-info alert">

  <label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 2em;">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" style="zoom: 1.5">
         <span>Text</span>
      </label>

</div>
```

Or you could just target the `input` and the `span`:

```
.form-check-input,
span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```